# How do you make Vim unhighlight what you searched for?

Tags: search, vim, highlight

I search for "nurple" in a file. I found it, great. But now, every occurrence of "nurple" is rendered in sick black on yellow. Forever.

Forever, that is, until I search for something I know won't be found, such as "asdhfalsdflajdflakjdf" simply so it clears the previous search highlighting.

Can't I just hit a magic key to kill the highlights when I'm done searching?

Comment: `/<mash keyboard>`

Comment: Definitely a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657447/vim-clear-last-search-highlighting and should be closed to direct people there

Comment: @BenCreasy why would one call an older post a duplicate of a newer one?

Comment: @Ruslan that one has nearly 10 times as many upvotes and they're both pretty old ('08 and '09)

Comment: Vim killing me with this one. I keep typing nohi, then when it doesnt work I type set nohi, etc. And everytime I need to google. But nohl works o_O. yup Im a noob x)

Answer (score 199, accepted):

Just put this in your .vimrc

```
" <Ctrl-l> redraws the screen and removes any search highlighting.
nnoremap <silent> <C-l> :nohl<CR><C-l>
```

Comment: Oooh, that's a goodie.  I've been using /@@<ENTER> which works as long as there's no @@ in my files.  I must modify my vimrc NOW!

Comment: This is great, cured a lot of my headaches!

I think ,it's better to use the full command in vimrc (:nohlsearch) to avoid conflicts in future.

Comment: <leader>c :nohl<CR> is a better option, I think.

Comment: @trillions - ctrl-l will only work if you start vim after editing .vimrc as shown.

Comment: Thats what I had been looking for  even after 6 years. May be too late. :)

Comment: @trillions Or if you do `:source %` in your current Vim session, then it will reload your .vimrc / init.vim (for NeoVim).

Comment: I've tried this code and run `source vimrc` but then it gives me `Unmatched ".` error. Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 387):

`:noh` (short for `nohighlight`) will temporarily clear the search highlight. The next search will still be highlighted.

Comment: @kmarks2 see you next leap year, I guess?

Comment: Just clarifying @steamer25's comment.

`:set nohlsearch` turns off search highlighting completely
`:nohlsearch` or `:noh` will clear the current highlight, but leave you in hlsearch mode for the next search.

Answer (score 91):

`/lkjasdf` has always been faster than `:noh` for me.

Comment: Doing this in front of someone who knew Vim better than I did is how I learned about :nohls.

Comment: That's gross! It adds `lkjasdf` to your search history.

Comment: then make `:noh` faster for you: `nnoremap <leader>h :noh<cr>`

Comment: Can't you just program vim to never include `lkjasdf` in the search history? Though, no, wait, that [would be more of an Emacs solution](https://xkcd.com/1172/)...

Comment: i came to the same conclusion, years ago, thanks mate

Comment: Yeah, I used to do ``/` `` (without the space), but then I found that some people start quotations with two backticks... So at the end of the day, `:noh` is the ultimate solution.

Answer (score 39):

```
" Make double-<Esc> clear search highlights
nnoremap <silent> <Esc><Esc> <Esc>:nohlsearch<CR><Esc>
```

Comment: Why is this not higher rated, this is simpler and more intuitive than a lot of the methods above.

Comment: Love this! Thanks!

Comment: Two questions: 1. why is the 2nd <Esc> necessary in the replacement? 2. do you know how to (temporarily) disable the escape bell for this?

Answer (score 20):

Then I prefer this:

```
map  <F12> :set hls!<CR>
imap <F12> <ESC>:set hls!<CR>a
vmap <F12> <ESC>:set hls!<CR>gv
```

And why? Because it **toggles** the switch: if highlight is on, then pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> turns it off. And vica versa. HTH.

Comment: This can also be accomplished with the "invhlsearch" setting.

Comment: I like this, but I think your `i` mapping would be better with `gi` instead of `a`. Either that or `<C-o>:set hls!<CR>`.

Comment: but `F12` is my yakuake key :(

Comment: @MaxCantor it looks like `invANYSETTING` is the same as `ANYSETTING!`.

Answer (score 16):

Append the following line to the end of your `.vimrc` to prevent highlighting altogether:

```
set nohlsearch
```

Answer (score 10):

```
            *:noh* *:nohlsearch*
:noh[lsearch]       Stop the highlighting for the 'hlsearch' option.  It
            is automatically turned back on when using a search
            command, or setting the 'hlsearch' option.
            This command doesn't work in an autocommand, because
            the highlighting state is saved and restored when
            executing autocommands |autocmd-searchpat|.
            Same thing for when invoking a user function.
```

I found it just under `:help #`, which I keep hitting all the time, and which highlights all the words on the current page like the current one.

Comment: On a side note, it's weird that one has to :noh to turn off search highlighting while instead of :hlsearch one has to set hlsearch to turn it on again.
(I guess I should't be surprised at vim "weirdiness"...)

Answer (score 5):

I think the best answer is to have a leader shortcut:

```
<leader>c :nohl<CR>
```

Now whenever you have your document all junked up with highlighted terms, you just hit <kbd>,</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> (I have my leader mapped to a comma). It works perfectly.

Comment: `map <leader>c :nohl<CR>` would be what you need in vimrc.

Answer (score 4):

I search so often that I've found it useful to map the underscore key to remove the search highlight:

```
nnoremap <silent> _ :nohl<CR>
```

Answer (score 3):

There is `hlsearch` and `nohlsearch`.  `:help hlsearch` will provide more information.

If you want to bind <kbd>F12</kbd> to toggle it on/off you can use this:

```
map     <F12>   :nohlsearch<CR>
imap    <F12>   <ESC>:nohlsearch<CR>i
vmap    <F12>   <ESC>:nohlsearch<CR>gv
```

Answer (score 3):

I have this in my .vimrc:

```
nnoremap ; :set invhlsearch<CR>
```

This way, <kbd>;</kbd> will toggle search highlighting. Normally, the <kbd>;</kbd> key repeats the latest t/T/f/F command, but I never really used that functionality. I find this setting much more useful, because I can change search highlighting on and off very quickly and can easily get a sense of where my search results are, at a glance.

Answer (score 3):

I think this answer in "[Vim clear last search highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657447/vim-clear-last-search-highlighting/657484#657484)" is better:

```
:let @/ = ""
```

Comment: `nnoremap <silent> <C-l> :let @/=""<CR>`

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you want to have a toogle and be sure that the highlight will be reactivate for the next time you search something, you can use this

```
nmap <F12> :set hls!<CR>
nnoremap / :set hls<CR>/
```

Answer (score -1):

I add the following mapping to my ~/.vimrc

```
map e/ /sdfdskfxxxxy
```

And in ESC mode, I press `e/`