# How to turn off Vim search highlighting

Tags: vim

i have  a pre-configured .vimrc file under ~/ ,after searching a term through '/' key,all items matched are highlighted,but after i find the need position and hit enter,the highlighted terms are still highlited... it's very disappointing since when i issue --c/"--,the screen is mashed with highlightings.which setting controls search highlighting facility?thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [vim clear last search highlighting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/657447/vim-clear-last-search-highlighting)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vim clear last search highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657447/vim-clear-last-search-highlighting)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Vim clear last search highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657447/vim-clear-last-search)

Answer (score 12):

You can issue `:nohl` to turn off highlighting until the next search. I would recommend mapping that to a key.

```
:map <F4> :nohl<CR>
```

If you want to turn off highlighting forever, use `:se nohlsearch` in your .vimrc

Answer (score 6):

If you type "`:nohls<enter>`" it will turn off the search highlighting.  (The next time you do a search, it will be highlighted, this is not a permanent setting.  It is useful for turning off the highlighting for the current search.)

Not sure if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: thanks,but i want some vim setting that control highlighting behaviour,not a command to remove the highlighting.