# How to get rid of search highlight in Vim

Tags: vim

I have `:set hlsearch` as default value.

When I search for something, search terms get highlighted. However many times I want to get rid of the highlight, so I do `:set nohlsearch`. In this way I get rid of highlights for the time being.

However if I do a new search, then search terms are not highlighted.

I would like to hit <kbd>ESC</kbd> + <kbd>ESC</kbd> to get rid of highlights and then set back `:set hlsearch`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [vim clear last search highlighting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/657447/vim-clear-last-search-highlighting)

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Try the `:noh` command.

[`vi/vim notes`](https://www.brezeale.com/?p=97)

Comment: How would you map :noh to <C-l> but keep <C-l>'s redraw behavior intact?

Comment: Not sure if that was part of the assignment, but if you insist, why not add `:redraw` to the mapping?

Comment: Thanks, used vim for years but was not aware of that one. I just wonder if it is possible for my fingers to unlearn /lkjlkj ?

Comment: it is my experience that fingers are very eager to learn new things, it just takes them ages to forget old ones ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  this isn't much different than doing /lkj tho...and actually takes more keypresses.  But does do exactly what we wanted and does not leave you with a warning at the bottom of the screen. ;)

Comment: It is different from `/lkj` in that you can use `n`, for instance, to go to the next match. In short, it doesn't alter the state, but hides the highlight. Of course, `/lkj` is often appropriate solution as well. The important part is to know know the difference ;-)

Comment: Why am i the only one to use `/asd` for this?

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker, nopes :( either my keyboard loves my left hand more or my typing has evolved in a different way..

Comment: @0xc0de, well, another hypothesis: some people want to alternate hands (`/` and then `asd`), some prefer to do the whole thing with one (`/` and then `lkj`). To tell you the truth, I have no idea to which category I belong, I use `:noh`.

Answer (score 46):

I use

```
/pleasedisablehighlightthanks
```

command.  Or just

```
/qewrufhiqwe
```

But you should be carefult not to mix this with the following command!

```
/qewrufhiqew
```

Comment: It would have the same effect like that of `:noh`, but you have to be careful not to hit something that can be found ;-)

Comment: This is the technique I've used - but the :noh turns of the highlights too (leaving the next search in highlight mode), so it is 'better'.  (All else apart, I end up with a 'Pattern not found: kkk' error message at the bottom, which has to be cleaned up to.

Comment: I just use /asdf, it's shorter :)

Comment: I am sure down-voters took it seriously and tried it... Upvote.

Answer (score 17):

```
:noremap <silent> <c-l> :nohls<cr><c-l>
```

This would redraw the screen and clear any search terms with Control-L, handy :) easier than reaching up to the F keys.

Answer (score 10):

I have the following in my `.vimrc`:

```
map <silent> <C-N> :let @/=""<CR>
```

Comment: Can someone walk me throug what's happening in this code. I don't get it.

Comment: `@/` is the register that contains the latest search term. This command clears that register, which has the effect that the search highlights disappear. It's sort of equivalent to `:nohls`.

Comment: I have the same :let mapped to <leader><leader> -- its a comfortable reach up to \

Comment: @jqno no it’s not equivalent, as it clears your search term, thus making :norm n (find next match) unavailable. :noh just turn off search hilite temporarily.

Answer (score 6):

This might suit your needs:

```
nnoremap <esc> :noh<return><esc>
```

With a little tinkering you can make it work in insert mode.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
set hlsearch!
nnoremap <F12> :set hlsearch!<CR>
```

and hit F12 to clear when desired. Use `:noh` in command mode to clear.

Answer (score 1):

you could search for something not in the text file.  Nothing will be highlighted in this case. (e.g. /349i5u9sgh)

Comment: that's what I do now. I am looking for a better alternative.

Answer (score 0):

This solution toggles the search:

```
nnoremap <silent><expr> <c-l> (&hls && v:hlsearch ? ':nohls' : ':set hls')."\n" <BAR> redraw<CR>
```