# Cancel the select pattern in VIM

Tags: vim

When I try to search some words in a article, it would highlight the pattern. After I have already found what I want, what should I do to cancel the select pattern, which means I don't want the words to be highlighted.

Best Regards,

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get rid of search highlight in vim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352242/how-to-get-rid-of-search-highlight-in-vim)

Comment: possible duplicate of [vim clear last search highlighting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/657447/vim-clear-last-search-highlighting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've mapped ESC-u to do this (like the less command):

```
nnoremap <ESC>u :nohlsearch<CR>
```

I learned that from this page: http://www.semicomplete.com/blog/geekery/make-vim-hlsearch-like-less.html

Answer (score 4):

The command you want is `:nohl`.

Answer (score 2):

Before I turned search highlighting off permanently, `/sdjrgjlsfj` was my preferred command.

Comment: +1. And I still do it, when working in the environment without my .vimrc.

Comment: This is what I am doing now, I want to know is there a better methond

Comment: :nohl would be better, search for non-exist pattern might be ridiculously slow when the file is huge.