# Get rid of Vim's highlight after searching text

Tags: vim

In VIM, after finding text with "/" command, that text remains highlighted.

What is the command to remove that? I don't want to remove highlighting capability at all, but don't want to have all those bright text spots once I've found what I need.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get rid of search highlight in vim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352242/how-to-get-rid-of-search-highlight-in-vim)

Comment: possible duplicate of [vim clear last search highlighting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/657447/vim-clear-last-search-highlighting)

Answer (score 152, accepted):

Type this:

```
:noh
```

Comment: ...which is short for `:nohlsearch`, which should help you remember it!

Comment: I have `:noh` mapped as such: `nnoremap <silent> <esc> :noh<cr><esc>` I find that hitting escape to be a natural vim way of clearing the search highlight.

Comment: It might be useful to note that this *doesn't* disable the search highlighting, it simply clears the current highlight (which is what I want).

Comment: @PeterRincker It's [said](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2615/26169) to not map `Esc`. [A problem I encountered doing this.](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/34647/mapping-esc-makes-vim-open-in-replace-mode)

Answer (score 34):

You can toggle it with

```
:set hls!
```

Of course a quick and dirty alternative is to do another search for gibberish:

```
/asdsad
```

I usually bind a key to `:set hls!` to make this easy and use the gibberish approach when I'm in vim on some machine I don't have my profile installed on.

Comment: Search for gibberish has some important downside: it adds garbage to search history. This may be inconvenient for some users the same way redundant highlighting distracts from work that has to be done.

Comment: If you happen to have the `'incsearch'` option on (which is a great option to have on), then searching for gibberish will make your screen jump at random places while typing said gibberish. Binding some normal-mode key to `:nohlsearch` is just so much better on all aspects.

Answer (score 28):

### Completely disable search highlights

```
:set nohlsearch
```

---

### Clear until next search

```
:nohlsearch
```

or `:noh` for short. This clears highlights until a new search is performed or <kbd>n</kbd> or <kbd>N</kbd> is pressed

---

### Clear on pressing custom map

- Clear highlights on hitting the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key

  ```
  nnoremap <esc> :noh<return><esc>
  ```
- Clear highlights on pressing <kbd>\</kbd> (backslash) twice

  ```
  nnoremap \\ :noh<return>
  ```

Comment: I try to keep my ~/.vimrc as minimal as possible, however this nice double-backslash trick found a place there -- thanks.

Answer (score 16):

I'm lazy and type something like `/asdf` then slap the `RETURN` key.

Answer (score 12):

I have this in my .vimrc:

```
map <leader>h :set hlsearch!<cr>
```

So when I type:

```
\h
```

It toggles highlighting on/off.

Answer (score 10):

If you don't want to remove highlighting one of the best ways is to clear the search register, unless of course you need the search items later. This will <strike>prevent you from having to re-enable the highlighting and</strike>*(Edit: `noh` does not permanently disable highlighting)* prevent you from accidentally jumping around. This is how I have mine setup:

`nmap <silent> ,/ :let@/=""<CR>`

What this does is map the key sequence `,/` in normal mode to clear the search register `@/` by setting it to an empty string. This is just an alternative to what has already been stated.

Comment: There are two gems in your answer. Why not combine them? `nmap <silent> ,/ :nohlsearch<CR>`.

Answer (score 3):

`:noh` will get rid of highlighted text.

Answer (score 2):

This might not be the most proper method, but control-L redraws the screen, clearing any highlighting in the process. This saves you from having to create another binding.

Comment: This does not work without creating the corresponding mapping

Answer (score 1):

In addition to “clear the search register”, you can even reset the search register to its previous value:

```
command! -nargs=* -range S
\ let atslash=@/|exe ':'.<line1>.','.<line2>.'s'.<q-args>|let @/=atslash
```

However:
  - this does not reset the previous status of `:hls`. I do not believe this to be possible in general.
  - this defines a new command, `:S`, to use in place of `:s`. You can use a `cabbrev` to map one to the other, but this will break when you add a range to the substitute command.

Answer (score 1):

[is.vim](https://github.com/haya14busa/is.vim) plugin has been pretty handy for me.
It automatically clears the searches in various scenarios, you just need
to install it via any plugin manager you use and it will do the work for you,
no need to do setup anything or change settings manually. It just works.

[image: is.vim gif]

(image taken from the official github repository)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29814228)