# Not highlighting search in vim if it is a part of a command

Tags: vim

In my .vimrc I've enabled highlighting the searched text (which I find to be a handy feature and wouldn't want to disable it).

```
set hlsearch
```

And, following answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372660/get-rid-of-vims-highlight-after-searching-text), I've made a mapping to be able to clear the highlight:

```
nmap <silent> ,/ :nohlsearch<CR>
```

The problem comes with commands which include search. For example, delete to next character 'x':

```
d/x
```

This will automatically highlight all the instances of 'x'. To remove this highlight I have to punch `,/` to clear it, which is quite annoying.

The question. Is it possible to enforce `:nohl` if the search is a part of a preceding command? Maybe, it is possible at least for a selected list of commands (say, `d`, `y` and `c`) before `/` character is hit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`d/x` does not work for me as you describe. (I'm on vim 7.3 here and it can't make sense of the `/` following `d` in normal mode, so disregards the `d` and starts a regular `/` search.)
If you want to delete to the next x, then `dfx` or `dtx` are what I would use (depending on whether you want to also delete the x itself or not).
No highlighting involved.
Hope that helps.

[Following some clarification in the comments.]
I'm thinking that it should be possible to write a custom function to do what you want, and then assign a custom key sequence to call that function.
I played around a little, but am not very well versed in vim functions and couldn't make it work.
Here's what I tried:

```
function! g:DeleteToSearchAndNohls(term)  
    :normal d/a:term  
    :nohlsearch  
endfunc
```

Comment: Did you try pushing Enter after d/x? This is what I have to do because search may contain several symbols and you need to tell vim where it ends.

Comment: This does provide a nice alternative to what I'm trying to do though. Thanks.

Comment: So `dtx` may not take you directly to your real target. In case you weren't aware of this, `.` will repeat the last action, so you can keep deleting to the next x easily until you do reach your target. That's probably still more work than you're already doing, though...

Answer (score 0):

If 'x' is on the same line than the cursor, you can use dtx (meaning delete to x).