# Clear search highlight on autocmd BufWrite

Tags: vim, autocmd

I tried most of the suggestions in those three questions:

[Get rid of Vim's highlight after searching text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372660/get-rid-of-vims-highlight-after-searching-text)
[How to get rid of search highlight in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352242/how-to-get-rid-of-search-highlight-in-vim)
[Vim clear last search highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657447/vim-clear-last-search-highlighting)

It's mainly the `:noh`, and it works when I type it manually. I just want it happen on BufWrite, so I tried multiple ways, none of which worked:

```
function! RemoveHighLight()
    :noh
endfunction

autocmd BufWrite * :call RemoveHighLight()
autocmd BufWrite * :noh
autocmd BufWrite * :execute "normal! :noh\<cr>"
```

Debuging `echom`s and `adebug\<esc>` in the function and in the third autocmd show that they execute successfully, just the `:noh` has no effect.

(Also tried `:let @/ = ""` which worked but it clears the search pattern, which is not I'm looking for. I just want to get rid of the highlight til pressing `n` or similar)

Using `BufWritePost` doesn't have effect, either.

Comment: According to the `:noh` documentation, this can't be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a workaround but you can set `nohlsearch` by autocmd. Then you can add a mapping to set it back by <kbd>n</kbd> and <kbd>N</kbd>.

```
au BufWrite * set nohlsearch
nnoremap <silent> n n:set hlsearch<CR>
nnoremap <silent> N N:set hlsearch<CR>
```

Or maybe better, check if it is already set

```
au BufWrite * set nohlsearch

nnoremap <silent> n n:call ToggleHlBack()<CR>
nnoremap <silent> N N:call ToggleHlBack()<CR>

function! ToggleHlBack()
  if &hlsearch == 'nohlsearch'
    set hlsearch
  endif
endfunction
```

Comment: That's a nice trick, thanks. There is a little bug, however. Is there a way to `set hlsearch` on next search? Because now it resets after n/N-ing but not on search+enter -ing. I'm more pedantic here than I have to be of course, I'm just curious ;d (older comment removed)

Comment: Sorry, that is true. I did not think about it. It could be done probably in a better way but you could add a mapping `nnoremap / :call ToggleHlBack()<CR>/`.