# Where does the mysterious line "1;3409;0c" come from

Tags: python, string, character

I spotted in my code a line that I never wrote:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#1;3409;0c

from math import exp
```

I think you can spot it yourself.

So I googled it, and it appears that nobody talk about it, but yet, it pops by itself in some places:

- http://home.gwu.edu/~maxal/pubs.html
- http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2014-November/024896.html
- https://github.com/alxlit/autoclave/pull/9/files?diff=split

Does somebody know where it comes from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be related to interaction between Vim and the terminal, according to a comment on [Why is vim starting in delete mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15014923/why-is-vim-starting-in-delete-mode/15015109#15015109)

> When built with the +termresponse feature, Vim sends a special control sequence (see :set t_RV?) to the terminal. When your terminal emulator see this sequence it responds with the sequence ESC ]>1;3201;0c.

There's also some stuff Vim may do when pressing the escape key in these cases, according to [Mapping <esc> in vimrc causes bizzare arrow behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11940801/mapping-esc-in-vimrc-causes-bizzare-arrow-behaviour/16027716#16027716)

> This ensures that the binding doesn't happen until after the term response is set, which prevents Esc from also sending a string like ]>1;3201;0c to vim.

So, I'm guessing that all the pages linked in the question has (at least once) been opened in Vim.

Comment: emacs too do this, something like `1;4601;0c`