# How to map <Esc> to quit vim - vim quits immediately after opening if mapped to :q<CR>

Tags: vim

I put this line in my .vimrc so that I could press escape to exit vim while in normal mode:

`:nnoremap <Esc> :q<CR>`

But now `$ vim` causes vim to flash up briefly and then exit every time.  Same with `$ vim filename`.

Removing the line restores normal behaviour.  Is there any way to get this functionality?  I am pretty sure that I had it working before but can't think why it would have broken between then and now.

Comment: I can't replicate your issue, have you added anything else that could be related in your vimrc. Do you have your .vimrc on github so we can look at it?

Comment: I can reproduce this with `vim -u ex.vim -N` where `cat ex.vim` is `:nnoremap <Esc> :q<CR>`. Can't when I have additional line `nnoremap <Esc><Esc> :nohlsearch`, or start vim with GVim. My vague guess is that the terminal sends escape sequence of some kind on startup. Possibly related to [vi - Vim has unexpected key presses on startup, what could be causing this? - Super User](http://superuser.com/questions/553601/).

Answer (score 2):

Vim can end up with some very strange behaviour when remapping `<Esc>`. I'd recommend using a different key for this if you don't want a headache.

See this question for reference: [Mapping <esc> in vimrc causes bizzare arrow behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11940801/mapping-esc-in-vimrc-causes-bizzare-arrow-behaviour)

Answer (score 0):

Adding `:set t_RV= ttymouse=xterm2` to .vimrc fixes the issue (see https://superuser.com/questions/553601/).