# What is wrong with this mapping? Vim starts in -- REPLACE -- mode

Tags: vim

I am having a weird bug in my `.vimrc` since I last updated it.

Every time I start vim it starts in `-- REPLACE --` mode which is really annoying.

I managed to find out that it is this line in my `.vimrc` that is causing the problem.

```
" Disable search highlighting temporally
nnoremap <esc> :nohl<cr>
```

The problem goes away when I comment this line out.

I am really confused about what is wrong with the mapping. It works as it should but causes vim to enter `-- REPLACE --` mode on startup.

I currently have no plugins enabled at all.

Comment: Well, that line isn't in your `.vimrc` ...

Comment: @wefwef: also check out [vi.SE](https://vi.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @0xC0000022L I have waited for this a long time!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is better to avoid mapping the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key, as it is known to cause strange behavior:

- [How to map < Esc > to quit vim - vim quits immediately after opening if mapped to :q< CR >](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29739356/717124)
- [Mapping < esc > in vimrc causes bizzare arrow behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11941648/717124)

I have been using `<leader><space>` for disabling the highlighting, as suggested by ["Coming Home to Vim"](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2010/09/coming-home-to-vim/#making-vim-more-useful), maybe you could get used to it too.

Answer (score 12):

I had this same problem, though it was inside of tmux, when I started vi (aka vim), it would launch in REPLACE mode. The culprit seems to be the TERMCAP definitions for the TERM I have been using: xterm-256color.

Once I set TERM to something different, vi (vim) worked correctly.
Even a TERM setting of "ansi" behaved better.

I settled on a TERM setting of "screen-256color-s" which works as I need.

Fun with TERMCAP definitions.

Comment: I had this issue with using Ubuntu on WSL. This worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've been able to get around the same problem by appending the following to my `vimrc` file:

```
" Terminal fixes
"
" These originate from some linux distribution's system vimrc. I can't say
" that I understand the details what's going on here, but without these
" settings, I've had problems like vim starting in REPLACE mode for
" TERM=xterm-256color (neovim is fine)

if &term =~? 'xterm'
    let s:myterm = 'xterm'
else
    let s:myterm =  &term
endif
let s:myterm = substitute(s:myterm, 'cons[0-9][0-9].*$',  'linux', '')
let s:myterm = substitute(s:myterm, 'vt1[0-9][0-9].*$',   'vt100', '')
let s:myterm = substitute(s:myterm, 'vt2[0-9][0-9].*$',   'vt220', '')
let s:myterm = substitute(s:myterm, '\\([^-]*\\)[_-].*$', '\\1',   '')

" Here we define the keys of the NumLock in keyboard transmit mode of xterm
" which misses or hasn't activated Alt/NumLock Modifiers.  Often not defined
" within termcap/terminfo and we should map the character printed on the keys.
if s:myterm ==? 'xterm' || s:myterm ==? 'kvt' || s:myterm ==? 'gnome'
    " keys in insert/command mode.
    map! <ESC>Oo  :
    map! <ESC>Oj  *
    map! <ESC>Om  -
    map! <ESC>Ok  +
    map! <ESC>Ol  ,
    map! <ESC>OM  
    map! <ESC>Ow  7
    map! <ESC>Ox  8
    map! <ESC>Oy  9
    map! <ESC>Ot  4
    map! <ESC>Ou  5
    map! <ESC>Ov  6
    map! <ESC>Oq  1
    map! <ESC>Or  2
    map! <ESC>Os  3
    map! <ESC>Op  0
    map! <ESC>On  .
    " keys in normal mode
    map <ESC>Oo  :
    map <ESC>Oj  *
    map <ESC>Om  -
    map <ESC>Ok  +
    map <ESC>Ol  ,
    map <ESC>OM  
    map <ESC>Ow  7
    map <ESC>Ox  8
    map <ESC>Oy  9
    map <ESC>Ot  4
    map <ESC>Ou  5
    map <ESC>Ov  6
    map <ESC>Oq  1
    map <ESC>Or  2
    map <ESC>Os  3
    map <ESC>Op  0
    map <ESC>On  .
endif
```

There's more settings like that in https://gist.github.com/goerz/36015f27c2a5423c64a5f9dc03865f2c which might also help. The root cause is something not being right in the termcap/terminfo