# Vim changes into replace mode on startup

Tags: vim

When I open a file with vim, I always start in replace mode.

I figured out, that when I remove this line from my .vimrc, I open files in normal mode again:

`nnoremap <esc> :noh<return><esc>`

If I exchange `<esc>` against a different key combination it also works as expected. I don't understand what is going on here.

[Here](https://github.com/CodingJonas/dotfiles/blob/master/.vimrc) is my complete `.vimrc`. I use termite, in case that could be a problem.

Comment: Thanks, I found the answer somewhere in a discussion in your linked question!

Comment: The question you linked is about the same topic, but the accepted answer to it did not solve my problem, that's why I added an answer here as well, stating the proper solution.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It was some internal problem, what solved the problem was adding this line:

`nnoremap <esc>^[ <esc>^[`

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20458579/4296244) you can find some details about this solution.

Comment: Duh, how is this answer not the accepted one? Works perfectly for me on WSL1 and properly keeps arrow keys working.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I answered myself here, but it didn't feel like an adequate solution. But if it helped you, too, I guess it should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 10):

This happened to me connecting to a cray from wsl. My .vimrc is pretty much empty; the distro has a default looking vimrc (no special nohl keymapping).

```
" FIX: ssh from wsl starting with REPLACE mode
" https://stackoverflow.com/a/11940894
if $TERM =~ 'xterm-256color'
  set noek
endif
```

Add this to vimrc and it no longer starts in REPLACE mode.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/11940894
(same thread Jonas mentioned).

Comment: this resets "nocompatible" for me with the effect that I cannot use backspace or arrow keys in insert mode (it just inserts ABCD etc. -- it is a known problem in vimwiki). Any solution for combining the both?