# vim starts in replace mode with filetype on

Tags: vim

There are a number of questions on here about vim starting in replace mode due to remapping `<esc>` [example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51388353/2069064).

I have a slightly different issue. It seems that my vim is starting in replace mode due to:

```
filetype on
```

This happens even if this is the *only* line in my `.vimrc`.

If I remove/comment out that line from my `.vimrc`, it starts fine. But with that line, replace mode every time. Which is fairly annoying as you might expect. This is using vim 8.0, on WSL. Is there a way to work around this?

Comment: can you show us your `.vimrc`? does this happen also if you put **only** `filetype on` in the `.vimrc` and nothing else? do you run `vim` inside `tmux` or similar? can you show content of `$TERM`?

Comment: @MarcoLucidi If the only line in my `.vimrc` is `filetype on`, this happens. I do not use `tmux`. `TERM` is `xterm-256color`

Comment: Start debugging with `vim -u NONE` to disable all configuration. If it's ok try `vim -u NONE -c "filetype on"` — still starts in replace mode? If not — the problem is rather in the runtime library.

Comment: @Barry are you using "Windows Terminal" to run WSL? this vim issue on github [#6365](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/6365) may be related to your problem

Comment: @MarcoLucidi That seems like it, yeah. I don't know what "Windows Terminal" is, I just open WSL and whatever terminal that is, that's the one I'm using.