# How to turn off highlighting after using search?

Tags: vim, highlight

Search highlighting becomes annoying after I've found the target word by using `/string` in vim.  Could someone tell me what is the quickest way to turn off search highlighting?  Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vim clear last search highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657447/vim-clear-last-search-highlighting)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The simplest way is to enter the `:noh` command.

Additionally, you can add this line to your `.vimrc` to map that command to the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, so you can simply press <kbd>Enter</kbd> after searching to clear highlight:

```
:nnoremap <CR> :noh<CR><CR>
```

- [vim clear last search highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657447/vim-clear-last-search-highlighting)
- [A Vim and ViEmu mapping you *really* can’t miss - never type `:noh` again!](http://www.viemu.com/blog/2009/06/16/a-vim-and-viemu-mapping-you-really-cant-miss-never-type-noh-again/)

Comment: by the way .. i've tried add that magic line but the vim become very strange .

Comment: in which line should i add this sentence?

Comment: My original post had it mapped to `Esc`. I've changed to to `<CR>` which is `Enter`. That may help, as I remember `Esc` acting kind of funny too.

Comment: ...anywhere in your `~/.vimrc` file.

Comment: @Yan note that you don't need the `:` in front of `nnoremap` to add to your `.vimrc`