# Vim: When sourcing vimrc, last search hl re-appears

Tags: vim

The title pretty much says it all. When I `:source $MYVIMRC` or `:source ~/.vimrc`, the last search re-appears. I can easily turn this off again with `:noh`, but it re-appears every time I `:source`.

This persists

- With a fresh `.vimrc`
- After deleting current MacVim install and downloading a fresh copy
- In iTerm using `vim`

I have checked in every file listed with `:version`, and other than my `.vimrc`, the only other file listed that isn't empty is `$VIM/vimrc` - which has only:

```
set nocompatible  
set backspace+=indent,eol,start  
set langmenu=none
```

I also tried the nuclear method: disable all plugins and pretend it's a fresh install:

```
mv .vim .vim-old  
mv .vimrc .vimrc-old  
touch .vimrc  
echo "set hlsearch" > .vimrc
```

The issue still occurs.

I'm pretty stumped as I don't recall this being the normal behavior; any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: :set hls turns on search highlighting... am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: @AndyRay Nope - but you did, in one short sentence, help me understand that I'm improperly clearing the last search by using `noh` - that doesn't clear the search, it simply turns off `hlsearch`; when I source my vimrc, it's re-enabling highlighting. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Credit to @AndyRay - I was misusing `noh` to get rid of the last search's highlighting, when instead I should be overriding the search term with `:let @/ = ""`.

See: [Vim clear last search highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657447/vim-clear-last-search-highlighting)

Answer (score 1):

Going off what Josh was getting at. Add the following to your `~./vimrc`:

```
" higlight search but not when sourcing .vimrc
set hls
let @/ = ""
```