# How to get rid of the brown background after searching texts in vi editor

Tags: search, background-color, vi

I am using vi editor. My problem is after searching some texts, say "something", if there are texts matching, the matched texts "something" will get brown background and it will not go away even I close the file and re-open it again. Too many matches make the text hard to read.
Does anyone know how to turn off this annoying background?

Comment: Did you take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/657447/vim-clear-last-search-highlighting

Answer (score 0):

As it is pointed out in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657447/vim-clear-last-search-highlighting) provided by Vijay type:

```
:set nohlsearch
```

You can get back to the highlight mode typing:

```
:set hlsearch
```

before next search.

Comment: Thanks guys! That's very helpful. BTW, I thought of a quick dirty solution for this yesterday. You can actually search something that you are sure won't be found. Then all the highlights will go. :)

Answer (score 0):

Or `:nohl` if you just want to turn off the current ones, without disabling the feature.