# Unwanted highlighting of pattern in VIM

Tags: regex, vim, highlight, vim-syntax-highlighting

In any type of file edited with VIM, I am seeing an unwanted pattern highlighted *everywhere* and I don't know how to turn *just that pattern* off. Or perhaps I corrupted a file accidentally. It seems like this happened recently after my thrashing around, experimenting with multiple windows (red herring?).

The pattern seems to be: the **letter e plus one character of any kind** ("eg", "el", "e.", etc)

[image: Highlighting of e plus any character]

Comment: yes, I believe so. I searched for e by accident trying to create panels. This was last week. It is all a blur, I think I was thrashing around trying things. That's when it seemed to happen.

Comment: You must have searched for `e.`.  You can always just search for something new (like `alsdkfjsaldkfj`) to change your most recent search term.  Better yet, check out the answers below that show you how to clear your most recent search term...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clear the highlight where text matches the last search pattern type `:nohls`

Comment: ```:noh``` seems to work too!

Answer (score 1):

It is probably the last thing you searched for. `vim` remembers it across restarts.

I keep this handy mapping in my `~/.vimrc`:

```
nnoremap \ :let @/ = ""<CR>
```

Then, I can use type `\` while in `COMMAND` mode in `vim`, and it clears the last search term.

I used to earlier use this:

```
nnoremap \ :set hlsearch!<CR>
```

This basically toggles search highlighting on/off when you hit `\`, but keeps the last search term in the `@/` register.

Answer (score 0):

For a permanent solution you can use something like ArjunShankar suggested. For a "fix just this time" I found this. The reason I couldn't find this initially was I didn't realize that when something is highlighted in VIM, it can be related to your *last search*.

```
:let @/ = ""
```

This was found via this thread: [Vim clear last search highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657447/vim-clear-last-search-highlighting)