# Why is 'const' always highlighted in vim when I write code with javascript

Tags: javascript, vim

I an studying how to use vim and I don't understand why 'const' is always highlighted.

[image: the question looks like this]

My vimrc:

```
set background=dark
set tabstop=4
set softtabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4

set autoindent
set smartindent

colorscheme janah
map <F3> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>

"set hlsearch          
set nowrap               
set shortmess=atI        

set nobackup
set autoread
"set showmatch
set ruler
autocmd InsertLeave * se nocul
autocmd InsertEnter * se cul

inoremap jj <Esc>
```

my plugs: auto-pairs, nerdtree, vim-javascript

Comment: Is this more appropriate for https://superuser.com?

Comment: This looks a lot like your colorscheme's highlighting for search. Do `:nohlsearch` to disable it temporarily.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I didn't know about it until I read your comment. I will try

Comment: StackOverflow is more for programming questions. This is more of a software configuration issue. -- Unless you were coding your own syntax highlights that is.

Comment: @ romainl  I didn't search for anything but it works. thank you

Comment: @evolutionxbox   I know it and thanks for your introduction

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vim clear last search highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657447/vim-clear-last-search-highlighting)

Comment: @evolutionxbox I would suggest vim.stackexchange.com. It's a combination of how (most likely) the default JavaScript syntax highlighter tags the `const` keyword and wha the `janah` color scheme specifies values with those tags to be displayed.