# Random brackets highlighted in VIM

Tags: c++, vim

So I'm coding in VIM, and I ran into a strange problem. I closed out of my source code, but when I opened it back up, a lot of my curly brackets are highlighted in yellow, and I can't seem to fix it. The closing brackets are matched up with opening brackets, so I don't see what the issue is.

Here is a picture of the problem: [image: http://puu.sh/mNEPE/1e64db4c52.png]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you make vim unhighlight what you searched for?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/99161/how-do-you-make-vim-unhighlight-what-you-searched-for)

Comment: Go back a screen; there's a problem with the bracketing in the previous function, for which there's a highlighted `}` at the top of what you show.

Answer (score 1):

Did you do a search for the closing bracket?

Try the following,  in command mode

```
:set nohlsearch
```

Comment: I have no clue how I accidentally managed to do that, but I guess so. When I type in

    :set nohlsearch

it gets rid of the highlighting, only until I write and close the code and then reopen it, at which point the highlighting returns.

Comment: @Benzel strange. You might have a plug-in of a setting in your .vimrc file that is causing the highlights to turn back on when opening your file.

Comment: As a shortcut, you could use `:noh`

Comment: Thank you @Atri this seemed to fix it.

Comment: Perhaps you pressed `*` or `#` in normal mode.  That will search for the symbol under the cursor.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:noh` to turn off highlighting of previously searched term.

Answer (score 0):

You can do `set nohl` that will turn off the `highlighting` for the session. Reopening will highlight again.

To fix that, search anything that you don't like, for instance  `/""`