# Need help trying to undo a VIM mistake

Tags: regex

So I'm practicing Ruby on Codeacademy and to save the work that I'm doing I copied and pasted my code onto my cmd prompt using VIM.  However, I noticed that each line of code was commented with the '#' symbol and I wanted to remove them.

To be productive,  I searched online how to use regex to search for all the hashtags and remove them with this command:

```
:%s/#//gc
```

Then this popped up:

```
replace with  (y/n/a/q/l/^E/^Y)?
```

I pressed y every time until the message disappeared and now I'm stuck with all hashtags characters being replaced with a yellow rectangle. So instead of having this:

```
#
```

I have this:

```
[] but shaded in yellow for every time I use a hastag.
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Perhaps, you wanted to run `:%s/^#//g` to remove all `#` at the beginning of the lines. `c` prompts you to confirm each substitution.

Comment: It does remove the hashtag symbol but it does the same thing where it highlights all hashtag characters.

Comment: Well,  I have no clue what the issue is now. Please check the answer below, maybe you are looking for something not related to the regex at all at this moment

Comment: No worries. The answer below helped. I really appreciate the help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/99182/3832970 is exactly what I got for a "stop highlighting vim" Google request :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The yellow rectangle represents the characters that matched your expression. To clear the last search highlighting, use:

`:noh`

To uncomment the lines of code, I would just do this:

1. Use `V` to select each line, then
2. `:norm x`

Comment: Thank you so much! I've learned something new today